# How to deal with comma in quote for csv file in Java?

Tags: java, csv, quotes, opencsv

<strike>I am using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read csv file. Fields are separated by comma. But in one field, if it contains quote, the comma inside the quote then is not a delimiter. For example, "Hello, World".</strike>

The current opencsv cannot deal with that. How to address this problem?

**update**

I found that it is not the problem of comma (so far). The problem row is:`...,"a children""s heart\",...`. It seems to remove the quote, thus the read field becomes `a children"s heart",......` and `......` represent all the following data.

It seems not the problem of opencsv, but mess of the input data.

Comment: First, file a bug report as `Ignoring commas in quoted elements` is stated in the features.

Comment: Do you want that to be returned as two fields, i.e. `"Hello` and `World"` ?

Comment: @milan I am now doing that based on opencsv

Comment: @tzaman I want them together.

Comment: It seems this is supported in 2.1 API, did you try playing with these parameters? char quotechar,
                 boolean strictQuotes

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom code to search through your csv file and replace all comma's that are inside quotes with a , or a special character that you can identify later and place back as a comma.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can supply custom separator and quote characters in the constructor, which should deal with it:

```
CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator, char quotechar)
```

Construct your reader with `,` as `separator` and `"` as `quotechar`.